# Get unique values from a nested list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a nested list (list of list) and I want to remove the duplicates but I'm getting an error. This is an example:

```
images = [
    [
        {
            "image_link": "1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg", 
            "catalogue_number": "1969.1523", 
            "dataset_name": "marine-transportation-transports-maritimes.xml"
        }, 
        {
            "image_link": "1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg", 
            "catalogue_number": "1969.1523", 
            "dataset_name": "railway-transportation-transports-ferroviaires.xml"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "image_link": "1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg", 
            "catalogue_number": "1969.1523", 
            "dataset_name": "marine-transportation-transports-maritimes.xml"
        }, 
        {
            "image_link": "1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg", 
            "catalogue_number": "1969.1523", 
            "dataset_name": "railway-transportation-transports-ferroviaires.xml"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "image_link": "1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg", 
            "catalogue_number": "1969.1523", 
            "dataset_name": "marine-transportation-transports-maritimes.xml"
        }, 
        {
            "image_link": "1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg", 
            "catalogue_number": "1969.1523", 
            "dataset_name": "railway-transportation-transports-ferroviaires.xml"
        }
    ]
]
```

So at the final this `images` will only contains

```
[
    [
        {
            "image_link": "1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg", 
            "catalogue_number": "1969.1523", 
            "dataset_name": "marine-transportation-transports-maritimes.xml"
        }, 
        {
            "image_link": "1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg", 
            "catalogue_number": "1969.1523", 
            "dataset_name": "railway-transportation-transports-ferroviaires.xml"
        }
    ]
]
```

I'm using the `set` function

```
set.__doc__
'set() -> new empty set object\nset(iterable) -> new set object\n\nBuild an unor
dered collection of unique elements.'
```

my trace log:

```
list(set(images))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

To make it simpler how can I remove all the duplicate in this example

```
example = [ [{'a':1, 'b':2}, 'w', 2], [{'a':1, 'b':2}, 'w', 2] ]
#result
#example = [[{'a':1, 'b':2}, 'w', 2] ]
```

Comment: unhashable type: 'list'

This means that it can't hash list, because list is mutable, you can't hash a mutable object, if your data is static you can change list for tuples.

Comment: The problem with the dicts is that even if you make them into tuples (immutable) you don't have any means to define the elements order, which would break the compare. 
A good solution would involve translating this data structure into immutable hashable data structure and then purging the duplicates (using `set` for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `set` and `dict` containers rely on hashing of data. Other mutable containers like `list` (and the `set` and `dict` themselves) cannot be hashed. They may be changed later on (mutable), so a constant hash value makes no sense.

But you could transform all your data to (nested) tuples and finally into a `set`. Since `tuple` is an **immutable** container - and your data is hashable (**strings**) - it can work. Here's a nasty one-liner for your special *images* case that does the trick:

```
images_Set = set([tuple([tuple(sorted(image_dict.items())) 
    for image_dict in inner_list])  for inner_list in images])
```

and

```
print(images_set)
```

prints

```
{((('catalogue_number', '1969.1523'),
   ('dataset_name', 'marine-transportation-transports-maritimes.xml'),
   ('image_link', '1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg')),
  (('catalogue_number', '1969.1523'),
   ('dataset_name', 'railway-transportation-transports-ferroviaires.xml'),
   ('image_link', '1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg')))}
```

**EDIT**: There's **no guaranteed order** for the `items` function of dictionaries. Hence, I also added `sorted` to ensure an order.

Comment: How about elements order when you translate dicts into tupples?
```CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.``` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

Comment: thanks @SmCaterpillar for your explanation. Thanks to Kasra, Avinash, Lucho y'all have great answer too.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
>>> example = [ [{'a':1, 'b':2}, 'w', 2], [{'a':1, 'b':2}, 'w', 2] ]
>>> l = []
>>> for i in example:
        if i not in l:
            l.append(i)


>>> l
[[{'b': 2, 'a': 1}, 'w', 2]]
```

Comment: thanks @Avinash! I guess there is no built_in functions for this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `compiler.ast.flatten` to flatten your list and then convert your dictionary to a hashable object to grub the sets then convert back to dict , Just with one list comprehension :

```
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> [dict(item) for item in set(tuple(i.items()) for i in flatten(images))]
[{'image_link': '1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg', 'catalogue_number': '1969.1523', 'dataset_name': 'marine-transportation-transports-maritimes.xml'}, {'image_link': '1969.1523.001.aa.cs.jpg', 'catalogue_number': '1969.1523', 'dataset_name': 'railway-transportation-transports-ferroviaires.xml'}]
```